# Navigate to another page, on clicking image using Colorbox

Tags: jquery, popup, colorbox

I can't seem to figure out how to navigate the user to another page, when clicked on the image using Colorbox. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Here is my code ->

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Pop up!</title>
    <link href="colorbox.css" rel="stylesheet"></link>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery.colorbox-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.fn.colorbox({href:"Pop_up_Int.jpg", open:true});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can't you just wrap image in an anchor element?

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle?

Comment: No, as you can see, everything is inside the head tag, and handled by colorbox.. or maybe i am missing something. Any ideas? :)

Comment: In jsFiddle, you're able to include external scripts. Check out the second tab on the left hand side of the fiddle page. Really, though, I just need to see what colorbox is populating in the `<body>`

Comment: Here it is. Though it is not displaying as it should in my browser, it servers the prupose
https://jsfiddle.net/vtt2ggce/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if the version of colorbox you're using will do the trick. The most recent version has a callback (onComplete) and you can utilize it as such:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var url = "http://www.passmark.com/images/monitortestscreenshot5.gif";
    $.colorbox({href:url, onComplete: function() {
        $('#colorbox img.cboxPhoto').wrap('<a href="'+url+'"></a>');
    }});
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bes2j53n/1/.

Comment: Thats it! I was using a pretty old version. Thanks!